# How to add attribute to root XML in my case?

Tags: c#, xml

XML is created by following code.

```
DataSet das = new DataSet();
das = ds.Copy();
das.DataSetName = "Stock";

das.Tables[0].TableName = "Assortment";
das.Tables[0].Columns[1].ColumnName = "Item";
das.Tables[0].Columns[2].ColumnName = "Quantity";
das.Tables[0].Columns[3].ColumnName = "Price";
das.Tables[0].Columns[4].ColumnName = "ValidDate";
das.Tables[0].Columns[5].ColumnName = "Summ";
das.Tables[0].Columns[6].ColumnName = "Manufacturer";
das.Tables[0].Columns[7].ColumnName = "Supplier";
das.WriteXml(LocalPath);
```

I get following xml:

```
<Stock>
  <Assortment>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>L - тироксин   Б/Х таб  100мкг  №50</Item>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    <Price>41496.0000</Price>
    <ValidDate>01.01.1999</ValidDate>
    <Summ>497952.0000</Summ>
    <Manufacturer>Заглушка</Manufacturer>
    <Supplier>Заглушка</Supplier>
  </Assortment>
  <Assortment>
    <ID>1242</ID>
    <Item>L - тироксин   Б/Х таб  100мкг  №50</Item>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    <Price>10.8000</Price>
    <ValidDate>01.01.1999</ValidDate>
    <Summ>129.6000</Summ>
    <Manufacturer>Заглушка</Manufacturer>
    <Supplier>Заглушка</Supplier>
  </Assortment>
</Stock>
```

How to add attribute to root XML? I want like this

```
<Stock Date="11.11.2013">
  <Assortment>
    <ID>1</ID>
    <Item>L - тироксин   Б/Х таб  100мкг  №50</Item>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    <Price>41496.0000</Price>
    <ValidDate>01.01.1999</ValidDate>
    <Summ>497952.0000</Summ>
    <Manufacturer>Заглушка</Manufacturer>
    <Supplier>Заглушка</Supplier>
  </Assortment>
  <Assortment>
    <ID>1242</ID>
    <Item>L - тироксин   Б/Х таб  100мкг  №50</Item>
    <Quantity>12</Quantity>
    <Price>10.8000</Price>
    <ValidDate>01.01.1999</ValidDate>
    <Summ>129.6000</Summ>
    <Manufacturer>Заглушка</Manufacturer>
    <Supplier>Заглушка</Supplier>
  </Assortment>
```

Adding date attribute to Stock.
Because I want to read Date when XML was created.
Thanks.

Comment: I'm not a lawyer, but it might not be prudent to be posting Russian XML files of what look like drug sale records.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just to flesh out `Heinzi`'s answer a little bit more, you can do the following:

I've added this as an extension method to add a Date Attribute to the root element of any dataset:

```cs
public static void WriteXmlWithCurrentDate(this DataSet ds, string fileName)
{
    // Create the MemoryStream to write with. 
    using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        // Write to stream with the WriteXml method.
        ds.WriteXml(stream);
        // Reset stream to origin
        stream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
        // Load stream as XDocument
        XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Load(stream);
        // get current date as string
        string today = DateTime.Today.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"));
        // Set date attribute on root element
        xdoc.Root.SetAttributeValue("Date", today);
        // Save to file as XML
        xdoc.Save(fileName);
    }
}
```

---

Then you could call it like this:

```cs
DataSet ds = new DataSet("Stock");
ds.Tables.Add(new DataTable("Assortment"));
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Item", typeof(string));
ds.Tables[0].Columns.Add("Quantity", typeof(Int16));
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Sock", 1);
ds.Tables[0].Rows.Add("Puppet", 2);

ds.WriteXmlWithCurrentDate(@"c:\temp\xml.xml");
```

---

Which will produce the following **XML**:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Stock Date="13.11.2013">
  <Assortment>
    <Item>Sock</Item>
    <Quantity>1</Quantity>
  </Assortment>
  <Assortment>
    <Item>Puppet</Item>
    <Quantity>2</Quantity>
  </Assortment>
</Stock>
```

---

For completeness' sake, here are all the API's involved

- Write an [Extension Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb383977.aspx) (*optional*)
- Create a new [`MemoryStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Wrap the `MemoryStream` in a [`using` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/yh598w02.aspx) so it automatically disposes
- Call [`DataSet.WriteXml(`*`stream`*`)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa57x5f2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), passing in the Stream
- Call [`MemoryStream.Seek`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.seek(v=vs.110).aspx) to position the stream at the beginning
- Create an `XDocument` by calling [`XDocument.Load(`*`stream`*`)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)
- Get the root element with [`XDocument.Root`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.root(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Add the current date with [`XElement.SetAttributeValue`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xelement.setattributevalue(v=vs.110).aspx)
- Save the `xDocument` as an XML with [`XDocument.Save`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: I will try your method and let you know

Comment: +1, thanks for working out the details! Two comments: (1) Since `MemoryStream` is disposable, I'd wrap it in a `using` block; (2) Russia uses [little-endian dates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Date_format_by_country#Map), so I'd use `DateTime.Today.ToString("MM.dd.yyyy")` or, even better, `DateTime.Today.ToString("d", new CultureInfo("ru-RU"))`.

Answer (score 5):

If you add your attribute to the extended properties:

```
das.ExtendedProperties.Add("Date", "11.11.2013");
```

you can write it with `XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema`

```
var das = new DataSet {DataSetName = "Stock"};
das.ExtendedProperties.Add("Date", "11.11.2013");
das.WriteXml(@"c:\temp\xml.xml", XmlWriteMode.WriteSchema);
```

Then if you want to read the value:

```
var xs = XNamespace.Get("http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema");
var msprop = XNamespace.Get("urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msprop");
var xml = XDocument.Load(@"c:\temp\xml.xml");
var attr = xml.Descendants(xs + "element").First();
var date = attr.Attributes().First(x => x.Name == msprop + "Date").Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible directly with `DataSet.WriteXml`. However, the following should work:

- Create a [MemoryStream](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
- use [`DataSet.WriteXml(Stream)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sa57x5f2%28v=vs.110%29.aspx),
- [load](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc838349%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the stream into an XDocument,
- modify the XDocument using [LINQ-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387061.aspx),
- [save](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb345830%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) the XDocument to a file.

Comment: I thought, it is easier. However I will try your method.

Comment: +1, Good Solution.  I fleshed this out a little [below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19935995/1366033)